# How do I restrict URL from being manually inputted in .net MVC?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

To clarify my title a little more:

I can't seem to find any information on how to restrict the access to a certain page, AND only allowing that access through a button click.

Example Situation:

I have a certain URL:   localhost:49423/Projects/Details/10    - If a user manually types this into his address bar, it should redirect to localhost:49423/Projects. I want specifically ID'd pages such as Projects/Details/10 to inaccessible unless accessed properly through my user interface.

I feel this may be impossible. Is this true? Is there a solution that requires some kind of button click or link click to access a page, and whenever a user accesses the URL, it verifies if a button/link click action has been taken?

Comment: Short answer is you cant. You could ad an additional query string value to indicate it was called by a button click, but a user could quickly work that out and type that value into the address bar. Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: It is unclear *why* you would want to do this. If you need to ensure the user logs in first, you should use the [`[Authorize]` attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) on your action method to prevent unauthorized access.

Comment: Yea it was more of a security thing, I wanted to limit the ability of a user to just type the project id into the URL and start looking at projects they shouldn't be. I have plenty of logic elsewhere to only render what a certain user should be seeing (his projects, projects shared with him, public projects), and all [Authorize] attributes are set up. There is probably a better way to institute this security measure, but this didn't seem _that_ hacky, although I am new to all of this. Kaplan's solution worked fine

Comment: Are you serious? Try it, then refresh the browser (which will destroy your value in `TempData`) - its nonsense to use `TempData` (or even `Session` for this). You test the value of the parameter in the GET method, and if the user does not have the permission to access it, then you throw and error or redirect.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Why is it nonesense to use TempData? He want's to access the page via button only. If he refresh the page  TempData will be destroyed and he won't be able to access the page. He can only access the page via the button he sets the TempData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TempData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/dd394711(v=vs.100).aspx#Anchor_2). 
When user click to a button, you can post your page and set a TempData and redirect to desired page. 
On Get request of desired page you can check if TempData is there. If it is there you can allow users to see the page and if not, you can redirect to you Projects page.